# cygcares-2.dll - missing from cURL library in cygwin install

Tags: curl, dll, cygwin

Hi I am wondering about cygcares-2.dll which is missing from my curl install in cygwin.

First I went in and installed with apt-cyg, then I reinstalled using the cygwin setup/install exe.

I was missing a few other dll's but I am still missing cygcares-2.dll and cannot find a version of it anywhere.

Output from the console when I do a cygcheck:

> > > cygcheck: tack_down: could not find cygcares-2.dll

Does anybody know where I might be able to find cygcares-2.dll?

Comment: Where did you get this curl package?  The curl packages in the Cygwin distro do not depend on this DLL.

Comment: Well, I solved that problem by aliasing to the windows installation curl.exe file.

But I ran into it again when I tried to run git clone:
 cygcheck /usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https.exe AND cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygcares-2.dll. That's the output.

Any idea?

Comment: You didn't answer my question.